# how to delete randomly generated id into sub node in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "likes" : {
    "-K_4PuiqVo6BsIsL0tMD" : {//post reference id
      "-K_4Pv_JXQHW_LoDNUJY" : {//'like' id(randomely generated)
        "id" : "TYS111088",
        "photoUrl" : "https://web.smm:8081/Emp_Images/Upload/Emp_Photo/t_TYS111088-c22cbe899f.JPG",
        "username" : "Anubhav"
      },
      "-K_4QP-lGvH9K2cljSIh" : {//'like' id(randomely generated)
        "id" : "TYS111088",
        "photoUrl" : "https://web.smm:8081/t_TYS111088-c22cbe899f.JPG",
        "username" : "Anubhav"
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to delete particular 'like'id node(with details),on click of dislike button. I am using android app.

Comment: Where do you want to accomplish this? what platform are you using? Android? iOS? or web app?

Comment: In the future, please post code and Firebase structures as text, not images, that way we don't have to retype it and it's also searchable.

Comment: I am using firebase in Android App @ koceeng

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the platform but the answer is very similar

```
    let ref = myRootRef.child("likes")
                       .child("-K_4Fbj0wBmZf3_l-uXe")
                       .child("-K_4FdjaJgPoR0EGwexB")

    ref.removeValue()
```

you can also delete data by setting using ref.setValue and setting it to nil.

Comment: like id is randomely generated,I need to perform delete operation on click of dislike button in Android app.

Comment: @Aniljaiswal The key doesn't really matter as you would need to query for the node you want by one of the children; in your case you could query for id = TYS111088. Once that node is returned in the snapshot, you simply get snapshot.key which would be -K_4FdjaJgPoR0EGwexB, and then you can remove the node.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have structured your data wrongly. You want to use on("child_added") on "likes". Once you have all childs, 
you want to delete a child via user input (e.g. you have a delete button with the referense to the current key)

When storing: `ref("likes").push()`

When retrieving: `ref("likes").on("child_added")`

Comment: I am adding child at 'like' node on likeClick button then wants to remove that child on dislikeClick button.But I am unable to remove that child node at 'like' node.

Comment: likes and dislikes are related to particular posts,posted by users@Salmin Skenderovic

Answer (score 0):

In the data viewer (what you're looking at) you can hover over a node and you'll have the ability to add a new child (green + button) or delete the node (red X button).

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove it via code.

Comment: like id is randomely generated,I need to perform delete operation on click of dislike button in Android app@Mike McDonald